# awk, grep usage for combining/comparing snmp output

Tags: bash, awk, grep, snmp

I have two snmpwalk outputs (non-sorted):

```
.248.194.136.249.4.240.0 = Counter32: 1
.248.194.136.249.4.240.1 = Counter32: 7
.248.194.136.249.8.112.0 = Counter32: 4
.248.194.136.249.8.112.1 = Counter32: 4
```

and

```
.248.194.136.249.4.240 = STRING: "building_1"
.248.194.136.249.8.112 = STRING: "building_2"
```

I'm trying to get an output similar to this:

```
building_1.0: 1
building_1.1: 7
building_2.0: 4
building_2.1: 4
```

I haven't been able to get this to work. Can this be achieved using grep within multiple awk statements? Is there a cleaner way to do it with awk?

**EDIT:** My attempts don't seem very relevant; since I'm uncertain if awk has the ability to do what I'm trying to do, I haven't been able to come up with a working attempt.

Comment: **Show us what you've tried so far.**  Don't describe it, but edit the question and paste in the actual code.  Then tell us what didn't work.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Don't get discouraged.  Awk can do this using techniques like `FNR==NR` to process `file2` prior to processing `file1` and associative arrays and lookups via keys etc...  How about posting attempts to process `file1` to get at the parts you want out of it separated and printing?  Like me, others have probably already worked out an answer and are just waiting to see your efforts.

Comment: `I'm trying to get an output similar to this:` - how similar does it have to be? If I just print the word `wombles` is that similar enough since it's also text? Hopefully you get the point that you need to help us understand your requirements if you want us to help you. Tell us PRECISE input and output and even more important explain the relationship between the two in terms of rows and columns, don't just say "I want to get this" without telling us why you'd expect that output.

Answer (score 1):

using awk

create a file named awkscript and add the following codes

```
FNR==NR{array[$0]=$0;next}
{gsub(/\"/,"")
for(i in array){
    split(array[i],name)
    match1=substr(name[1],0,22)
    if(match1==$1){print $4 substr(name[1],23,2) ": " name[4]}
}
}
```

run script

```
awk -f path_to_awkscript  path_to_fileA   path_to_fileB
```

where fileA contains

```
.248.194.136.249.4.240.0 = Counter32: 1
.248.194.136.249.4.240.1 = Counter32: 7
.248.194.136.249.8.112.0 = Counter32: 4
.248.194.136.249.8.112.1 = Counter32: 4
```

and fileB contains

```
.248.194.136.249.4.240 = STRING: "building_1"
.248.194.136.249.8.112 = STRING: "building_2"
```

**testing output**

if fileA contains

```
.248.194.136.249.4.240.0 = Counter32: 1
.248.194.136.249.4.240.1 = Counter32: 7
.248.194.136.249.8.112.0 = Counter32: 4
.248.194.136.249.8.112.1 = Counter32: 4
.248.194.136.249.4.243.0 = Counter32: 1
.248.194.136.249.4.243.1 = Counter32: 10
.248.194.136.249.8.115.1 = Counter32: 13
```

and fileB contains

```
.248.194.136.249.4.240 = STRING: "building_1"
.248.194.136.249.8.112 = STRING: "building_2"
.248.194.136.249.8.115 = STRING: "building_10"
```

The output will be

```
building_1.1: 7
building_1.0: 1
building_2.1: 4
building_2.0: 4
building_10.1: 13
```

Note also

```
.248.194.136.249.4.243.0 = Counter32: 1
.248.194.136.249.4.243.1 = Counter32: 10
```

**The above do not have a building address in fileB that corresponds to a line in fileA, therefore it is omitted**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the **best** way to do this, but this got me close enough to where I wanted to be:

```
awk -F"[.| ]" 'FNR==NR{f1[$2$3$4$5$6$7]=$0;next}$2$3$4$5$6$7 in f1{print f1[$2$3$4$5$6$7], $0}' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
.248.194.136.249.4.240 = STRING: "building_1" .248.194.136.249.4.240.0 = Counter32: 1
.248.194.136.249.4.240 = STRING: "building_1" .248.194.136.249.4.240.1 = Counter32: 7
.248.194.136.249.8.112 = STRING: "building_2" .248.194.136.249.8.112.0 = Counter32: 4
.248.194.136.249.8.112 = STRING: "building_2" .248.194.136.249.8.112.1 = Counter32: 4
```

Which can easily be manipulated into the output I was aiming for.